# Check if coordinate rectangle contains CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am using a special Map SDK for iOS and I am adding a custom shape to the map. The shape is always a different size and it could be a circle, square, star etc. the point being it is always dynamic whenever the app is run.

After adding this shape to the map, I can access it's property called `overlayBounds` which is described as: `This property contains the smallest rectangle that completely encompasses the overlay.`

The `overlay` is my shape that I'm adding to the map.

Whenever a location update is generated by `CLLocationManager`, I want to check and see if the most recent coordinate is inside of that `overlayBounds` property of the shape.

When accessing `overlayBounds`, it has an `ne` property and a `sw` property. Both of these are just `CLLocationCoordinate2D's`

So, if the `overlayBounds` is made up of two `CLLocationCoordinate2D's` and the `CLLocationManager` is always updating the user's location and giving me the most recent coordinate(`CLLocationCoordinate2D`), how can I check if that most recent coordinate is within the `overlayBounds`?

After doing a lot of research I have only found one potential solution to go off of which is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30434618/3344977

But that answer assumes that my `overlayBounds` property has 4 coordinates(`CLLocationCoordinate2D's`), when I only have 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description seems much harder then the actual question. So if I am getting this correctly your question is only to check if the point is inside the rectangle described in `overlayBounds`.

You have only 2 points as it is enough to define a rectangle. So `NE` and `SW` are the two points where the other two are received as `(NE.x, SE.y)` and `(SE.x, NE.y)`. With this you may use the answer you linked or you may simply construct a `MKMapRect` where origin is `NE` and size is `SE-NE`. So in this case you may simply use `MKMapRectMake` and then use `MKMapRectContainsPoint`. BUT watch out when computing size as `SE-NE` might produce negative results in which cases you need to add degrees to the size. That is 180 to `x` (latitude) and 360 to `y` (longitude)...

```
MKMapRect rect = MKMapRectMake(NE.latitude, NE.longitude, SE.latitude-NE.latitude, SE.longitude-NE.longitude);
if(rect.width < .0) rect.width += 180.0;
if(rect.height < .0) rect.height += 360.0;
BOOL pointInside = MKMapRectContainsPoint(rect, pointOnMap);
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Now if you are trying to check if the point is inside the shape itself it really depends on how your shape is defined. If this is some form of analytic representation you might find some method already made for you to return the value but if not then your best shot would most likely be drawing the shape to some canvas and checking the color of canvas at the location you need to check. In any case the bigger problem here is converting the point and the rect to a Cartesian coordinate system. If that is the case then just add a comment and I will try to help you on that...